# Building Questionnaire Form with Yii

Tags: php, yii

Is it possible to create a dynamic questionnaire with Yii ?
The layout might look like this :

```
                   | Yes | No | Not Sure |
Section 1          
- Question A       |     |    |          |
- Question B       |     |    |          |
...
Section 2
- Question C       |     |    |          |
- Question D       |     |    |          |
...
```

*Note: The answers for each question will be radio buttons*

The "Sections" and "Questions" should be dynamic, an administrator can add/edit/delete those items. Each Section and Question has an "ordering" number (stored in database), and it is sorted according to those values. (For example, Section X have and ordering value of **2**, Section Y has **1**. On the questionnaire, Section Y will displayed **first**, then Section X displayed **second**)

The questionnaire might be more complex.
There are some "redundant questions" in one or many Sections, for example :

```
Section 1          
- Question A
- Question B
- Redundant Question X
- Redundant Question Y
- Redundant Question Z
Section 2
- Question C
- Question D
- Redundant Question X
- Redundant Question Y
- Redundant Question Z
```

Thus, it should be separated to another part of the questionnaire.
That part of the questionnaire should be like this:

```
                         |      Section 1      ||       Section 2     |
                         | Yes | No | Not Sure || Yes | No | Not Sure |
Redundant Section 1          
- Redundant Question X
- Redundant Question Y
...
Redundant Section 2
- Redundant Question Z
...
```

Is it possible to create this type of questionnaire with Yii ?
If so, how is the correct way to do this ?
(Assumption: I think the standard Zii Widgets aren't enough to achieve this, I should build a custom widget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Look into the Yii CForm system, it will help you a bunch. You may not even need custom widgets

Edit: here's a [link to the CForm guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.builder)

Comment: I tried looking at `models/LoginForm` class, the original one from a standard Yii project (generated with `yiic`). It always has 3 attributes: `username`,`password`, and `rememberMe`.  How can I modify the class so that those attributes are dynamic, retrieved from database ?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you give me links to the tutorial or explanation of CForm system ?

Comment: @topher added a link to the CForm guide